# Glassfish/Wildfly not failing if @Resource cannot be resolved?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, servlet-3.0, glassfish-4.1

I am experimenting with `@Resource` in a servlet to see if we can use it to inject configuration parameters easily (this is servlet 3.0 webapp in Glassfish 4.1.1).

I was told in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45715196/53897 that the behavior I saw of a `@Resource String userName` being null when used if it could not be resolved if the env-entries in web.xml were not present, to be wrong according to the specification, but that the behavior of WildFly was the same.

Question is:  Is this a known bug?  Is there a flag that can enforce the "fail if not resolvable"?

Comment: I chatted with one of the WildFly devs about this and he asked me to raise a ticket. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-9235. If this is indeed found to be a bug then it is something that the TCK is not catching, which is why GlassFish missed it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is allowed for simple env entries:

EE.5.4.1.3

....
It’s often convenient to declare a field or method as an injection target, but
specify a default value in the code, as illustrated in the following example.

// The maximum number of tax exemptions, configured by the Deployer.
@Resource int maxExemptions = 4; // defaults to 4

To support this case, the container must only inject a value for this resource if
the deployer has specified a value to override the default value.
.....

Comment: Sigh.  Whoever thought this was a good idea apparently never had to deal with a faulty configuration entry silently ignored and it is still in Java EE 7 (page 84).  Defaults are a bad idea for these things. Question is if the wording requires for a default value to be provided or if the null case is ok too?   Sigh again.